# Few shot learning in object detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, object-detection

I am working on a project to detect buildings from satellite imagery in Tanzania using convolutional neural nets. I use a pre-trained model which I further train on a selected area in Tanzania.

The model performs well (f1 score ≈ 0.85) when tested on an area near where it was trained but much worse (f1 score ≈ 0.3) when tested in a region further away. To tackle this issue, I thought I could use few-shot learning - I would first train the network on a large dataset in one region and when I want to use the model in a different region, I would fine-tune it with a few examples from that region.

However, when I read about few-shot learning, for example [in this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/few-shot-learning-in-cvpr19-6c6892fc8c5) or in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.06957v1.pdf), they describe it as a method for learning **new classes/categories** from few examples. But I don't want the model to learn new classes. I want it to learn to recognize **the same class**, only on images looking slightly different than those used for training.

**Question:** Is few-shot learning suitable for what I want to achieve? If not, what could I use instead?

Comment: You might check out semi-supervised stuff.

Comment: Few-shot learning can be used to enhance existing models as well. However it is not guaranted that it will perform better, but you can try